# Adding "open as root" to the right-click context menu of nemo

Tags: debian, root, cinnamon, menu, file-manager

Since many files and applications seem to need root for proper operation or for allowing edits and having to use the console is too inconvenient, I'd like to have right-click context menu options for "Open file as root" and "Start application as root" (and maybe also "Create new file/folder as root") in nemo.

- What's the best way to add such context menu entries?
- Is there any reason to not add such?
- If there is none of significance why isn't it featured in the OS itself similar to the "Run as administrator"-option in Windows?

I'm using Debian 9.0 with Cinnamon and its standard nemo file manager.

**Edit**: User terdon informed me about the "Open folder as root" menu-entry which somewhat solves the "Open file as root" part.

Edit: **don't open files as root like this! If files need root something is probably broken.** There are only very few exceptions where root is needed and this should usually be done by running `sudo command`. I recommend using the **Dolphin** file explorer instead of nemo and **KDE** instead of Cinnamon.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what desktop environment and what file manager you are using. These aren't global OS options, they will depend on the specific tools you are using. That said, if you think using the command line is inconvenient, Debian is probably not the right distribution for you and you should switch to something like Mint or Ubuntu. Many (most?) *nix users find using the GUI inconvenient so don't care about this sort of option. I, for example, don't ever use a file manager since the CLI is so much simpler and more powerful. It's just a matter of what you're used to.

Comment: Alright, done. And sorry, but I find Debian to fit perfectly for me. It's just that Debian needs to change. It needs to advance to become more convenient. Those users need to start to care about this sort of option. If you want FOSS to live and thrive you'll come to that conclusion as well. If you want it to become increasingly irrelevant, only used by a small circle of elitist users and overtaken by proprietary software and companies you ignore anything related to convenience, practical use and just-as-powerful GUIs. It's that simple, really.

Comment: Um. Wow. All I said is that Debian might not be the best choice for you because it is aimed at experienced users. But, as I said before, this has nothing to do with Debian and everything to do with, in this case, Cinnamon. If you want to complain at someone, target the Cinnamon devs, not Debian. And there are *many* distributions that are designed for regular users and they will probably have adapted their version of Cinnamon to do this out of the box. You have just chosen not to use one.

Comment: Do you have the "Open as root" option when right clicking on a directory? I see that on my nemo, cinnamon 3.4.3 running on Arch. If you do, would opening the parent directory as root and continuing from there be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: Didn't mean to be offensive; sorry if it sounded like that or as if I was complaining about devs. I'm just asking questions that I'm interested in and which would at the same time make Debian more user-friendly. I'm an experienced user when it comes to computers in general but not with GNU/Linux. However I think that systems should be designed so that even casual users can use them well enough so that they can *become* experienced over time. Didn't know it was a Cinnamon issue so that's helpful and hence I also added it as a tag. Not sure if other distros have it. Either way it would 1/2

Comment: 2/3 probably be useful for many people who have the same distro as me *and* as I hope for a clean, stable, 100% FOSS (with that I also include open hardware and drivers and all the installed applications) system to replace proprietary systems on a large scale. Ubuntu is good for getting more casual people onboard on the short term but it's not the means to this end. I want to help *make* Debian to be designed *also* for regular users. (Aside of that from a quick search it seems Ubuntu doesn't feature this context-menu either.)

Comment: 3/3 Yes, I also have that "open folder as root" context menu entry. Didn't notice that one so far (only checked the right-click menus of files & apps). It doesn't cover the "Run program as root" issue (I open apps via the panel) but it's basically ¾ of what I was looking for. So thank you very much!

Comment: mYnDstrEAm Debian is also a good choice for the beginning, I also started there and got it learned and managed, it's a good and stable distribution, very OK for all knowledge levels

Comment: A side note: you might want to erase many of you knowledge about what you might think the OS is. In Windows you just have one built in file manager ('explorer.exe') which also provides the desktop manager and you have no choice about your window manager. In Linux the OS is just the OS and you are free to install many file managers, desktop managers, window managers, … and choose your favorite as default. So maybe another file manager like spacefm, pcmanfm, or any other, would simply just fit your needs better then nemo. (And I am sure you already knew this, but however…)